# How do I change the order of integration of a triple integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

The original integral is:

$\int_{0}^{3}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{9-z^2}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{9-y^{2}-z^{2}}}dxdydz$

I am asked to change this into an integral with the order of $dzdydx$. How do I do this? I have no idea where to start.

Comment: I suggest you to draw the graph and then try to do integral with this order $dzdydx$

Comment: Leyla's method will of course work but can be hard to visualise; writing all integrals to be from 0 to infinity and making the integrand an indicator function provides a more algorithmic approach which readily generalises to n dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

A hint:

This triple integral serves to compute the volume of a certain three-dimensional body $B$. Before you start interchanging the order of integration get a clear pictorial idea of what this body is. When this is accomplished set up the order of integration as prescribed.